# Display field's content as an image

Tags: 7, entities, webforms

I'm using webform_multiple_file. To display my submissions, I created a view and added as field **Webform submission data: Value**

To customize my view I used **print $fields['value_1']->content ;**

This displays somthing like this:

> image1.png
>
> image2.jpeg

But I want to display just the first data and as an image like

```
<img src="image1.png" />
```

Below the HTML return

```
<div class="webform-multiple-file"><a href="http://localhost/mydrupal/sites/default/files/webform/image1.png">image1.png</a></div><div class="webform-multiple-file"><a href="http://localhost/mydrupal/sites/default/files/webform/image2.jpeg">image2.jpeg</a></div>
```

Any idea please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
file_dir  = $file_create_url("public://");

print '<a href=' . $file_dir . '/'. $fields['value_1']->content . '</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks Sir. I edited my question to add the html returns by using $fields['value_1']->content